# How can i seed data from a csv file in Rhodes

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have seen in Rhomobile we can seed the local db from local files. The file need to be text file, and the format something like this,

```
client_id|last_sync_success
67320d31-e42e-4156-af91-5d9bd7175b08|
```

But can i have some way to seed data from a csv file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below,

```
# For seeding question to question table from question.csv file
if MyModel.find(:all).empty?
  file_name = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication.get_app_path('public')+'sample.csv')
  file = File.new(file_name, "r")
  while (line = file.gets)
    col = (line.gsub("\n", "")).split(";")
    MyModel.create( {"id" => col[0].gsub('"',''), "text" => col[1].gsub('"','')} )
  end
end
```

Hope this helps you.